# Printing a .txt file in VC++ windows form application with default printer

Tags: visual-c++, printing, dev-c++

I'm relatively new to VC++. I made a program that outputs a .txt file to a folder in my computer. I'm wondering if there is a method that allows me to send that file to the system's default printer (in this case my home printer) without needing to see the printer dialog box, just send the file to the pinter's queue and print it.

Thanks

Comment: [`ShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx) with `print` verb

Comment: I used ShellExecute(0, L"print", L"C:\\Users\\text.txt", 0, 0, 0); and got error C3861: 'ShellExecute': identifier not found

Comment: Did you `#include <Shellapi.h>`, as specified in the fine manual?